# Best way to join tables with ranges of dates

Tags: mysql, date, range

I have a very simple question but i can't find a good solution.

```
Table A:
ID_A DateStart  DateEnd    no_days
1    2019-02-01 2019-02-04 3
2    2019-02-04 2019-02-06 2

Table B:
ID_B ID_A Date        DaysToDate
1    1    2019-02-01  10
2    1    2019-02-02  9
3    1    2019-02-03  8
4    2    2019-02-04  7
5    2    2019-02-05  6
```

So i'm starting with Table A and after having created one record, i create N rows for Table B.

In my project i'll then need to do the join

```
select * from TableA join TableB using(ID_A)
```

in order to have all the days listed, with their own "days to this date" value. I need the join because my user could be searching for a range of days and i need to know how many rows of TableB are involved in this search.

This is all good, it works really fast but the database is growing A LOT and i'm sure there has to be a more intelligent way to solve this problem, maybe with a static "Days" table simply listing one row per day in for the next 100 years...but i can't find a working solution because i need to keep speed and the "days to date" value.

The results i need are of this kind

```
select * from TableA join TableB using(ID_A) where DateStart between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-05'


ID_A DateStart  DateEnd    no_days ID_B  Date        DaysToDate
1    2019-02-01 2019-02-04 3       1    1    2019-02-01  10
1    2019-02-01 2019-02-04 3       2    1    2019-02-02  9
1    2019-02-01 2019-02-04 3       3    1    2019-02-03  8
2    2019-02-04 2019-02-06 2       4    2    2019-02-04  7
```

Do you have any hints?

Comment: There's not actually anything wrong with constructing a utility table - and a table holding dates for the next 100 years is a depressingly small thing. That said, it's not usually necessary - and, in MySQL 8.0+, can be easily simulated anyway using CTE.

Comment: BTW, in your result, you have 7 column headings but 8 columns !?!

Comment: i made a mistake in the second part, columns are 7 indeed, numbers before "Date" are not supposed to be there. So do you think it's a standard way of doing this one? Mysql 5.7